# While Device id and Device model is getting listed for a device in mobilefirst console, User id not getting generated for the same device. Why?

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-console, mobilefirst-console

At what point of time does the user id get generated in the Mobilefirst console  when a new user downloads an android application which runs in a mobile first server ?

Answer (score 0):

User id is not generated in the console. If you are referring to the device id and userId in the DEVICES tab, then note that this userId is the one that you authenticate with , in your application.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/c_device_access_mgmt.html?lang=en

Comment: I have set my user id in the WL.Client.setActiveUser. But I am unable to see my user id in the Worklight console Devices tab. Can anyone say what do I do now  ?

Comment: There is no such client side API. If you authenticate properly into a user realm, you will see the userid in the DEVICES tab. Try out any of the authentication samples at: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/hybrid-development/. Also, update the post with what you have done